How to disable default documentation of tomcat which comes after hitting application url
When ever I am trying to access my appurl like below give me tomcat related details, I want to disable this webpages and it should give me 404 Not Found message.
google.com/docs/
google.com/examples/

I tried looking it in web.config file but wasn't able to find.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Delete all the folders under %TOMCAT_HOME%/webapps besides manager, ie delete ROOT, docs, examples, host-manager, etc
